# Updating GUI by modifying a variable from another class not working java

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to disable a JButton in the GUI class, by incrementing the turn variable from another class - the test class. This is a simplified and modified excerpt from a bigger school project. Trying to modify the view or GUI from the controller class based on data given back from the model.

This is the GUI class

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test implements ActionListener {

private int turn;
private JFrame d;   
private JButton a;
private int clicked;

public test() {
clicked=0;
turn=0;
d = new JFrame();
a = new JButton();
d.add(a);
a.addActionListener(this);
d.setSize(75,150);
d.setVisible(true);
}

public int getTurn() {
    return turn;
}

public void setTurn(int turn) {
    this.turn = turn;
}

public int getClicked() {
    return clicked;
}

public void setClicked(int clicked) {
    this.clicked = clicked;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new test();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clicked=1;
    if(turn==3) {
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
    }

}

}
```

While this is the class that attempts to make the GUI changes

```
public class test2 {
private int turn;
private test gui;

public test2() {

    gui = new test();
    while(gui.getTurn()<3){
    play();
    }
}

public void play() {
    if(gui.getTurn()<=3 && gui.getClicked()==1) {
        gui.setTurn(gui.getTurn()+1); //update the turn variable in the gui 

        gui.setClicked(0);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new test2();
}
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: `if(turn==3)` - where is `turn` updated?

Comment: How can this be true? `if(gui.getTurn()>3`

Comment: Also `play` method is only going to be entered into `once`

Comment: Thanks i updated it but unfortunately still does not work @ScaryWombat

Comment: TBH I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.  `while(gui.getTurn()<3){
    play();
    }` is going to be looping very fast and any multi^threaded updates are not going to be noticed.

Comment: Basically am trying to continuosly call play until gui's turn variable is 3. In play am incrementing the gui's turn based on every click of the button @ScaryWombat

Comment: Yes, but you are also not `firing` a click event

Comment: Yes is that wrong? or is it conflicting in a way? @ScaryWombat

Comment: @osayi Yes, it's wrong. You taking a procedural approach to an event driven API

Comment: Oh interesting. In what ways could i change the implementation so that it only represents one approach. Also what is the better approach? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @osayi What is the better approach?  If you're using Swing (or other UI framework) then you should work with the framework in the way it was intended to be used. Maybe start with [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for a better understanding of how the framework works.  Essentially though, the "turn" would need to be updated on some event generate by the UI, such as button action